# How to generate OpenStack compatible images?

Tags: image, opensuse, openstack

i have a two node OpenStack Diablo Cluster up and running. I tried to get the small tty-Linux Image running and it worked without problems.

In my naivity i now tried to get my own OpenSuse images working wich i created with OpenSuse Studio. I have tried .vmdk and .raw running with:

glance add name="My-raw" is_public=true container_format=bare disk_format=raw < /cloud/images/My_Appliance.raw

launch per dashboard or euca-run-instances ...

I use qemu as libvirt_type. The instances will be shown as running but i cannot ping them nor is there a console output, so guess they are not started correctly. /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log and /var/log/libvirt/qemu/instance-xx.log show no errors.

Is it even possible to run those images without kernel and ramdisk? If not, how do i get/generate these?

Answer (score 0):

With libvirt, you should be able to run raw or qcow2 images, you don't need a kernel or ramdisk. Try testing with one of the QCOW2 [Ubuntu cloud images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/oneiric/current/) (e.g.,  oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img)

See also the [Image Management chapter](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/ch_image_mgmt.html) in the OpenStack Compute admin guide. This chapter has information on where to get images, as well as how to create them.